# Enterprise ASP.NET MVC 3 architecture outline

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

I've gotten lucky enough to work on a completely new enterprise MVC 3 project. And by new, I mean source control is literally empty at this point.

We're trying to figure out how to lay out out the solution and various projects that will be needed.

We'll be using Razor, WCF, Entity Framework, Moq, Ninject, SpecFlow, MSTest, and CodedUI.

Can anyone point me to a well-laid-out enterprise application that I might be able to use a model for our application structure? I.e. solution and project structure.

All the examples of MVC projects I've found have very poor separation of concerns, and we want to make sure we do this thing right.

Help? :)

Comment: So, where is the architecture? You dont even name half the tools / areas needed for a full enterprise architecture.

Answer (score 7):

I've found [Project Silk](http://silk.codeplex.com/) to be pretty good structurally.

Comment: Why oh why would anyone bundle up source in a .exe?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this sample](https://github.com/darind/samplemvc).

Answer (score 2):

If I'd to choose I'd take **[SharpArchitecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/)**. But if you're new to Asp.Net MVC its pretty big and if you look at the Northwind sample, there are some Asp.Net MVC specific - maybe I'm too strict by saying it - *antipatterns* in it (leaking Domain Objects into view, not one-view-one-viewmodel,...)

Taking the things I've learned there and *understanding the structure* called "**Onion Architecture**" by looking [here](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/), I propose a basic project structure like I pointed out **[in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990773/how-asp-net-mvc-architecture-fits-into-the-traditional-multi-layered-architectur)**.

It's "basic", as it gives you no example project but an **overview of a general well structured web app** which uses **Asp.net MVC, ORM, DI** and **some good practices** for using Asp.Net MVC "right".

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [WhoCanHelpMe](http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com) (http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com), it follows SharpArchitecture, and although it's using NHibernate you can still understand its architecture easily.